# How to preserve onclick when pasted to a contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a link and a contentEditable div. The link has a `onclick` property. When I copied the link and pasted it into the contentEditable div, the `onclick` property was removed. Is there anyway to preserve the property in contentEditable?

### Details

[image: Description]

### Snippet

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <a href="#" onclick="handleClick()">Click me</a>
      <div
          style="border: 1px solid black; min-width: 100px;"
          contenteditable="true">
      </div>
      <script>
        function handleClick() {
          console.log("clicked");
        }
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you mean, copied into `<div>`? Can you show?

Comment: `onclick` seems to be working fine inside the div

Comment: @AjAX. Yes, and I added a gif animation to help illustrate my question. Tell me if it's still not clear.

Comment: @Swordys I added a gif animation to help illustrate my question, could you check if's the same result on your side?

Comment: You mean copying a `link`. It is — not — the `HTML` you are copying. %)P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser strips event handlers for you to prevent XSS. But if you're sure it's ok to keep potentially dangerous things in the pasted HTML, you can customize `onPaste` handler:

```
const editable = document.querySelector('[contenteditable]');
editable.addEventListener('paste', function(event) {
    const dataTransfer = event.clipboardData;
    const html = dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, html);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This is just a proof of concept, and there's *a lot* more you would need to do to make this work reliably in different browsers.